# How to enable/disbale a button in mxml depending on whether count is less than 10 or not

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

I am trying to bind enabled property of my button to the maximum value that an integer can attain. I need this button to allow user to view next page and want to disable this button when all the components have been shown (as reflected in count).

Something like :

```
<mx:Button label="Previous" click="nextHandler()" enabled="{count< 10}">
```

But the compiler is throwing an error that '<' attribute can not be used in enabled tag.

Any ideas over this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrnans answer is spot on, but if you dont wish to use the XML/Html "&lt"; then the following also works:)

```
<mx:NumericStepper id="count" x="10" y="15" maximum="20"/>
<mx:Button label="Previous" enabled="{count.value >= 10 ? false : true}" x="10" y="45"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian !! Its precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The following will work:

```
<mx:Button label="Previous" click="nextHandler()" enabled="{count &lt; 10}"/>
```

Just tested it with:

```
    <s:NumericStepper id="count"/>
    <mx:Button label="Previous"  enabled="{count.value &lt; 10}"/>
```